# What kind of data is highly relational

Tags: sql, database, nosql

I'm new to databases, and is exploring SQL vs noSQL.

What kind of data is highly relational and benefits from SQL and what kind of data does not?

Please provide some examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should I use document based database instead of relational database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441441/why-should-i-use-document-based-database-instead-of-relational-database)

Comment: Highly relational stuff: book-keeping (general ledger), inventory and order/sales systems, almost anything that's currently existing under the "line-of-business" application umbrella, really...

Comment: Things like menus with parent child rankings and boss-employee rankings are usually considered hierarchical and less suited to and more difficult to work with in a relational database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relational data fits into the definition of a [*relation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28logic%29):

- A header defines a finite set of columns.
- Each column has a *name* and a *data type*.
- Data types are a named, finite set of distinct values.
- Each column in a given row of the relation contains *one* value of the appropriate data type for the respective column.
- Rows have no implicit order.
- Columns have no implicit order.
- Duplicate rows are not allowed.

These conditions are prerequisites for all the [Normal Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) of relations.  That is, a table doesn't qualify even for First Normal Form unless it's a relation.  Many operations in SQL don't work right if the table isn't relational.

To be more practical, a relational table must have the same properties on every row, by the same names, and must have a primary key defined over one or more columns so you can reference each row individually.

NoSQL is actually a marketing term used to brand and promote some data management products.  It's not a computer science term.

But if you mean *non-relational*, then you can see that a non-relational data store is allowed to break some of the rules above:

- Two entries (rows) in a given collection can be duplicates.
- The fields can vary per entry.  Different number, different names, different data types.
- A given field can contain the same value in two entries, yet the value is considered different for some reason (for example, depending on the value in another field).
- Order of entries is significant (for example, the entries are assumed to be in chronological order).
- Order of fields is significant (for example, the first field is assumed to be a key of some kind).

But by breaking these rules, you lose the foundation on which relational operations work.

Comment: "A header defines a finite set of columns": I think you meant to say, "A *heading* defines a finite set of *attributes*". Similarly, your use SQL or otherwise informal terms to try to express the meaning of 'relation' and to be honest I don't think it works -- I think just a link to a formal definition would suffice ;)

Comment: @onedaywhen: Thanks, I do support using precise terminology where I can, but a StackOverflow post is not the place to introduce people to all the terms needed for formal definitions.  I make a few sacrifices and use informal terms that will be more familiar to readers.  For a more full description of what it means to be a relation, I'd recommend "SQL and Relational Theory" by C. J. Date.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be burdened with a few misconceptions. *Relational* as in Relational Database refers to a type of data model - the system of representation used for data. *Any* information that consists of facts (propositions) can be represented relationally if your DBMS supports that type of information. There is no intrinsic quality of any information that makes it more or less suitable for an RDBMS.

SQL is a (strictly non-relational) database language.

NOSQL is a loose term that can be applied to any database system that doesn't use SQL or that extends the capabilities of SQL. NOSQL and relational are *not* mutually exclusive concepts. NOSQL does not have to mean "non-relational", it just means "not SQL".

Comment: So what? Mark asked what data works **well** with SQL; and he did not bring up the popular “NoSQL is a single thing” misconception.

Comment: He asked "What kind of data *is* highly relational", which is what I was trying to answer.

Comment: +1 I assume by "representation" you are referring to both structure and operators ;)