# Why would I want to use a non-relational database?

Tags: database, relational-database, non-relational-database

The latest craze in databases seems to be centered around non-relational databases. Why? It seems kind of counterproductive. For example, it makes much more sense to me to express my data in a relational way (example code in Django + SQL for tables):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_create = True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_create = True)
```

SQL:

```
create table post (id int primary key auto_increment,
        name varchar,
        created datetime);

create table comment(id int primary key auto_increment,
        text text,
        post_id int,
        created datetime,
        foreign key post_id references post(id));
```

The power of SQL is that this information can be expressed in  *so* many ways. Sure, the whole object-relational-mapping problem exists, but I look at it as a feature and not as a problem. With SQL, I can fetch all distinct comments of a given post which are older than yesterday, collate all of those together, and generate statistics. Can the same be done for non-relational databases?

It also would seem to really impact performance to use a non-relational database like MongoDB because you would immediately grab an entire object graph, rather than what you minimally need.

Can someone explain to me what the benefits are of using a non-relational database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441441/why-should-i-use-document-based-database-instead-of-relational-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I use document based database instead of relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441441/why-should-i-use-document-based-database-instead-of-relational-database)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [CAP Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem)

And the [PACELC interpretation](http://dbmsmusings.blogspot.com/2010/04/problems-with-cap-and-yahoos-little.html)

Relational databases tend to make one set of trade-offs, and non-relational tend to make a different set of trade-offs.  For massive distributed datasets, non-relational sometimes makes more sense.

There is also a sense in which non-relational databases can eliminate a lot of the ORM pain, but again there are always tradeoffs.  In some use cases, non-relational storage can be faster, because all the data for a particular hierarchy can be stored closer together on the disk.  Also note that non-relational databases do still have query capabilities.

In the end, it's about making the appropriate set of trade-offs for your particular use-case.

Comment: can you explain more on "all the data for a particular hierarchy can be stored closer together on the disk"?

Comment: @wwwwan - "storing data hierarchy closer together on disk" is rarely that important. SSD storage makes it even less relevant. Both relational and non-relational dbs employ caching etc.  A relational store would generally require retrieving data from multiple tables (typically stored on different disk pages) whereas a non-relational store *could* (very much depend on the implementation) put all the data for a particular hierarchy on a single/fewer disk page since it would tend to view the hierarchy as a single "document". Could make a difference in severely resource-constrained systems.

Comment: While SSD removes the locality advantage, still in distributed systems locality plays a very big role (at a higher scale).

Answer (score 0):

Look at Nosql : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

It's basically because of scalibility and performance.