# Serving files through flask + redis

Tags: python, ajax, redis, download, flask

This might be a bit of a noob question, so I apologize in advance.
How do I make a web server running flask+redis serve binary files as a response to a link/query?

I want the response to the link to be either some AJAX action such as changing a div, or popping up an "unavailable" response, or to serve back some binary file.
I would like help both with the client side (jQuery / other Javascript) and the server side.

Thanks!

Side question: Would you choose redis for this task? Or maybe something else such as MongoDB, or a regular RDBMS? And why?

Comment: For your side question, refer to this [nice thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441441/why-should-i-use-document-based-database-instead-of-relational-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would configure your webserver so that URLs that refer to static files are handled directly by the server, rather than going through Flask.

Comment: Yeah... This is a pretty strange situation, where the webpage is actually the report of some test suite that I run, and its "links" need to be to content which might or might not be available.